# Error to add a new field into AggregateResult

Tags: apex, soql, query, aggregateresult

I have this query:

```
[SELECT SUM(Amount) total, owner.Name ownername, Name oportunityname, Account.Last_Meeting_Date__c from Opportunity o where ownerid =: u.id GROUP BY ownerId, owner.Name, Name, Last_Meeting_date__c];
```

I added this field `Account.Last_Meeting_date__c` and when I try to save this Apex Class show me this error

> Error: Compile Error: No such column 'Last_Meeting_date__c' on entity 'Opportunity'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 19 column 24

And I need get the Last Meeting Date from any Opportunities.

Any idea. 
Thanks.

Comment: In your `GROUP BY` clause try adding `Account.Last_Meeting_date__c` instead of `Last_Meeting_date__c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Last_Meeting_date__c while grouping the records.This is a field of account. Modify your query as follows.

```
[SELECT SUM(Amount) total, owner.Name ownername, Name oportunityname,Account.Last_Meeting_Date__c 
 from Opportunity o where ownerid =: u.id 
 GROUP BY ownerId, owner.Name, Name, Account.Last_Meeting_date__c];
```